# all the varchar columns in all the tables from sybase

Tags: sap-ase

Does anybody know how can we get the list of all the columns in all the tables which are varchar?
i need it in below format:

```
<column_name> <table_name>
```

i tried this:

```
select o.name [TableName], c.name [ColumnName]  from sysobjects o 
inner join syscolumns c on c.id = o.id inner join systypes t 
on t.usertype = c.usertype where o.type = 'U' and o.name in ("MYTABLE")
```

but the above gives the list of all columns.
if i can find a way then i can put all the table names inside  last braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use where systypes.name = 'varchar', or systypes.type = 39, or syscolumn.type = 39 to narrow your query to just varchar columns.

```
select o.name, c.name from sysobjects o, syscolumns c
where o.id = c.id
and c.type = 39
and o.type = "U"
```